# What is the value of createElement?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
render: **h** => h(App)
```

What is the value of 'h'?

Does Vue itself give value to 'h'?

Is the value of 'h', a method?

Notice that 'h' equals to 'createElement'.

It's my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

And it's my App.vue file:

```
 <template>
  <div>Hi there!</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App"
};
</script>
```

Comment: You can find the answer to your questions here: https://css-tricks.com/what-does-the-h-stand-for-in-vues-render-method/

Comment: @nemesv Unfortunately I couldn't find out the value of 'h' in that link.

Answer (score 1):

It stands for [hyperscript](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx/issues/6). Like you've noticed it's a conventional shorthand for `createElement` and you can replace `h` with `createElemement` or another name if you prefer. They use `createElement` in the [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) for render functions.